# When to release. Instruments says I have a leak

Tags: objective-c

Sometimes I wonder where I would be able to get great information other than from the stack overflow community. I suppose the Objective-C memory management handbook wouldn't be bad, but I feel like you guys can tell me *why* as opposed to just what to do.

I have the following code:

```
NSString* rawTickerData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: op.requestData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray* lines   = [rawTickerData componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

for(NSString* line in lines)
{
    NSArray* fields = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    if([fields count] > 1)
    {
        [self.tickerData addObject:fields];
    }
}
    [rawTickerData release]
```

Instruments tells me that `fields` is leaking, but trying to release it after the if statement or doing an autorelease gives an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

The same thing happens for `lines`. Releasing it anywhere or trying to do autorelease gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS or "trying to double free" (for autorelease).

Yet, instruments is still saying that these are leaking. Am I missing something?

Comment: `[line componentsSeparatedByString:@","]` ... This gives you an `NSArray` containing `NSString` s, right?  So, who owns the strings and where are they released?  Is there an `NSAutoreleasePool` involved?

Comment: Mike, you may be on to something. Looking closer at the leaks information, it looks like there are a lot of leaked CFStrings, and `[line componentsSeparatedByString:]` is listed as the culprit.



`line` should be released when the for loop runs out of scope (right?) and the NSArray `fields` is added to `tickerData`, which is released in the dealloc method. Do I need to do anything with the strings returned in the array?

Comment: Mike, you couldn't have known what the issue was, because it was due to me retaining a delegate instead of assigning it. Little mistakes will kill you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, the code you've posted is correct. `fields` is an autoreleased object that gets retained when added to `self.tickerData`. `lines` is also autoreleased, so it isn't leaking (at least not in the code shown).

If you're leaking anywhere, it's because you're not properly cleaning up self.tickerData. If you comment out the `[self.tickerData addObject:fields];` line, are you still getting leaks reported? If not, make sure you're calling `[tickerData release]` (or something similar, like `self.tickerData = nil`) somewhere, probably in your `dealloc` implementation.

Comment: Robot K, I marked you as correct, because you were right that the tickerData wasn't being released. You also set me on the right path by saying fields and lines are autoreleased.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases the best practice is to release your object's at the end of each loop, if you retained them. In this case your `fields` variable gets an `autorelease` object, the best option is to use an `NSAutoReleasePool` to release your objects at the end of the loop.

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool;
pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSString* rawTickerData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: op.requestData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray* lines   = [rawTickerData componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

for(NSString* line in lines)
{
    NSArray* fields = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    if([fields count] > 1)
    {
        [self.tickerData addObject:fields];
    }
    [pool drain];
}
[rawTickerData release];
```

This will flushes all the autoreleased objects if they are don't needed. If you dont use autorelease pool, your objects are living until your method terminates.
If this doesn't resolve your leak problem i suggest to initialize your array like this:

```
NSArray *lines = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[line componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
//and release at the end of the loop
[lines release];
```